# Exact CUDA / cudNN versions for TensorFlow 2.4.0

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use Anaconda3 (2020.11 with Python 3.8.5 64-bit) with Tensorflow 2.4.0 on Windows 10 but I must say this technology seems to be still very... unstable!

It's really puzzling to understand that each library depends on an exact version of another library, not more, not less!

So far I managed to install:

- Anaconda3 (2020.11 with Python 3.8.5 64-bit)
- tensorflow 2.4.0
- CUDA 11.0.2, runtime only, using network installer
- cudnn-11.0-windows-x64-v8.0.4.30
- GeForce drivers 461.09-desktop-win10-64bit-international-dch-whql
- board is a Geforce RTX 3070

Which according to the manual https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu should be OK but unfortunately I'm still getting the dreaded `"Error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows"` message.

Here's the complete trace:

```
2021-01-20 20:53:25.785203: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.173495: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-20 20:53:29.175299: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.213308: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3070 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-20 20:53:29.213536: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.237764: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.237865: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.244635: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.247913: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.262791: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.268091: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.278049: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.278203: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-20 20:53:29.279054: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-01-20 20:53:29.281144: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3070 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-01-20 20:53:29.281321: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.281786: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.282156: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.282961: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.283385: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.284167: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.284635: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.286872: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:29.289197: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-20 20:53:29.772262: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-20 20:53:29.772375: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0
2021-01-20 20:53:29.773599: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
2021-01-20 20:53:29.774277: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6589 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-01-20 20:53:29.775166: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-20 20:53:30.414473: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-01-20 20:53:31.860756: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:32.450199: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:32.476605: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-20 20:53:33.172408: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:336] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2021-01-20 20:53:33.172484: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:340] Error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
```

Judging from the documentation this might be related to using the wrong combination of libraries but really I don't have a clue: any test I might be doing to troubleshoot this?

Comment: not sure if this helps but tf-nightly-gpu 2.5.0.dev20210120 does not give this issue but instead it kills the runtime

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the GeForce drivers 461.09-desktop-win10-64bit-international-dch-whql. It includes CUDA 11.2, not 11. I guess you need to find a GeForce driver version compatible with your card that includes CUDA 11. It looks like version 450.36.06+ could work for you.
I'd recommend you uninstall CUDA 11.2 and the current drivers from your computer and install the older versions.